# Как сделать вырезанный круглый уголок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, border

Как сделать этот уголок на всех углах и только справа и только слева? Буду очень признателен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете создать фигуру-псевдоеоемент ::before со свойством background: transparent;  и подогнать его под угол абсолютным позиционированием , вот тут есть геометрические фигуры https://m.habr.com/ru/post/126207/ возможно, есть решение и получше

Answer (score 7, accepted):

если какие то сложные контуры то нам на помощь приходит `Масштабируемая векторная графика`

css pattern взял от [сюда](https://freefrontend.com/css-background-patterns/) просто для красоты

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  --c: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  --t: transparent;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pat-1 {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, var(--c) 0, var(--c) 20px, var(--t) 20px, var(--t) 32px, var(--c) 32px, var(--c) 44px, var(--t) 44px, var(--t) 56px, var(--c) 56px, var(--c) 68px, var(--t) 68px, var(--t) 80px, var(--c) 0), repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--c) 0, var(--c) 20px, var(--t) 20px, var(--t) 32px, var(--c) 32px, var(--c) 44px, var(--t) 44px, var(--t) 56px, var(--c) 56px, var(--c) 68px, var(--t) 68px, var(--t) 80px, var(--c) 0), linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FC354C, #0ABFBC);
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="col pat-1"></div>

<div class="item">
  <svg viewBox="0 -3 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="m52.380952-1.5148544h246.1339v297.0297h-297.0297v-248.49128c30.122584-5.621327 43.413738-14.248579 50.895804-48.538428z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="6"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

если не хочется на свг, то можно впихнуть что-то такое)

p.s. можно чуть рефакторнуть, но мне лень

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block::after,
.block::before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block::before {
  top: 0;
}

.block::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.block__inner {
  position: relative;
  height: inherit;
}

.block__inner::after,
.block__inner::before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block__inner::before {
  left: 0;
}

.block__inner::after {
  right: 0;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(2) {
  top: -30px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(3) {
  left: -30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.corner:nth-child(2),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  right: -30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.corner:nth-child(2),
.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__inner">
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: А как забрать фон ?

Comment: @ПавлоСмолинець, не понял, чуть поточнее